# Invoke event listener only on inner element (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

I've got a `div` inside another `div`. Both have event listeners attached to run a function on mousedown - call them `outerDivFunction` and `innerDivFunction`. When I click the inner `div`, both functions are invoked; I'd like it to only invoke  `innerDivFunction`.

How to do this? (Vanilla solutions are preferred to jQuery.)

Comment: Check this out too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914587/javascript-event-delegation-handling-parents-of-clicked-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event's `stopPropagation()` in `innerDivFunction`. This prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

For more details: [Event Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation)

```js
function outerDivFunction(){
  alert('Outer Div');
}

function innerDivFunction(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('Inner Div');
}
```

```css
.outer{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.inner{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" onclick="outerDivFunction()">Outer Div
  <div class="inner" onclick="innerDivFunction(event)">Inner Div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Avoid** at all costs the use of `Event.stopPropagation()`. An application (or third party code) should **never** stop or prevent an Event to propagate through layers, components. Rather check for `Event.target.closest("selector")` matches and act accordingly. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74812690/383904)