# How to have a different onClick event for the child element without affecting the parent one?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, event-bubbling, event-capturing

Having the following structure:

```
<div class="the-parent">
  <div>
    <a onClick="doParentStuff()">
      <div>
        <i onClick="doChildStuff()"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, when the child element (icon) is clicked it logs the content of `doChildStuff()` but afterwards it also logs the content of `doParentStuff()`.

Is there a way to call `doChildStuff` only when the icon is clicked and call `doParentStuff` when everything else inside `the-parent` div is clicked?

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Then, utilize [event delegation](/a/34896387/4642212) with [`closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [`contains`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

Comment: Related: [Javascript event delegation, handling parents of clicked elements?](/q/9914587/4642212). [`composedPath`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) can also be used. Make sure you’re aware of [potential caveats of `stopPropagation`](/q/54815439/4642212) and read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: I would suggest removing all `onclick` attributes, then adding this JS: `addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => { const iElement = target.closest(".the-parent a i"), anchorElement = target.closest(".the-parent a"); if(iElement){ doChildStuff(); } else if(anchorElement){ doParentStuff(); } });`. I’d also suggest reconsidering the usage of `<a>`. See [Accessibility concerns of the `<a>` element](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#onclick_events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the child is clicked, you must `stopPropagation` of the event:

```js
function doChildStuff(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('child clicked');
}

function doParentStuff() {
  console.log('parent clicked');
}
```

```html
<div class="the-parent">
  <div>
    <a onClick="doParentStuff()">
      <div>
        Test
        <button onClick="doChildStuff(event)">Child</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid** the use of `Event.stopPropagation()` (unless you really, really know what you're doing).
An application, or third party code, should never stop or prevent an event to propagate throughout the application layers / components.
Instead, change your logic to implement a third function (like `doStuff`) that will trigger a desired function depending on the `Event.target.closest()` match

```js
const doChildStuff = () => {
  console.log("child stuff");
};

const doParentStuff = () => {
  console.log("parent stuff");
};

const doStuff = (ev) => {
 if (!ev.target.closest(".icon")) {
    doParentStuff();
 }
 doChildStuff();
};

document.querySelectorAll(".anchor").forEach(elAnchor => {
  elAnchor.addEventListener("click", doStuff);
});
```

```html
<div class="the-parent">
  <div>
    <a class="anchor">
      <div>
        Link
        <i class="icon">icon</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, stop using HTML inline `on*` attribute handlers. Such code is hard to maintain and debug. JavaScript should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Use addEventListener instead.

Even if not asked, if you want to also separate the handler for the parent, simply put it into an `else` block:

```js
const doChildStuff = () => {
  console.log("child stuff");
};

const doParentStuff = () => {
  console.log("parent stuff");
};

const doStuff = (ev) => {
  if (!ev.target.closest(".icon")) {
    doParentStuff();
  } else {
    doChildStuff();
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll(".anchor").forEach(elAnchor => {
  elAnchor.addEventListener("click", doStuff);
});
```

```html
<div class="the-parent">
  <div>
    <a class="anchor">
      <div>
        Link
        <i class="icon">icon</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code snippet doesn't work fine, it logs both messages when it should log only one

Comment: @LeoMessi but you asked that behavior only for the icon - which indeed respects the asked question requirement. If you click on the icon - only one log will be present instead of two.

Comment: @LeoMessi otherwise the fix is simple as putting `doChildStuff();` inside and else block: like: `else { doChildStuff(); } `. That's it.

Comment: @LeoMessi sad to see another stopPropagation answer getting into account - teaching other people getting to this pages really bad coding habits :(

Comment: Edited the answer to add that other example as well. @LeoMessi